# How do you stop a function from being executed and only execute on click in mootools

Tags: html, mootools

I'm new to Mootools and I have found that I have to use the click element but I'm not 100% sure where I am meant to put it in the below code:

```
function setInStockOption (labels, e) {
    active = false;
    labels.some (function (item,index) {
        if(item.hasClass ('selected')) {
            if(item.hasClass ('unavailable')) {
                item.removeClass('selected');
                item.addClass ('unselected');
                active = true;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(active) {
            if (!item.hasClass ('unavailable')) {
                e.target = this;
                item.fireEvent ('click', e);
                active = false;
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}

window.addEvent('load', function(e) {
    var labels = $$('div.option-radios label.radio');

    setInStockOption(labels, e);
});
```

I basically need to add the class selected on click instead. At the moment this script is adding the selected class to the first child of Radio in the html and then when you click on others it'll add the class selected. I basically want all the classes to be unselected when the page loads
.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want something like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(e) {
    $$('div.option-radios label.radio').each(function(label, i) {
        label.addEvent('click', function(event) {
            event.target.toggleClass('selected');
        });
    });
});
```

Note that this uses the `Array.each` method instead of `Array.some`. The latter doesn't do what you expect. It then registers a `click` event on every label which simply toggles the `selected` class on the event target.

Then you can add other initialization code to the `each` loop and more logic to the click event handler.

I also used the `domready` event which is usually preferred over `load` since [it fires earlier](http://demos111.mootools.net/DomReadyVS.Load).

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6EYR/) to play around with.